# firebase and gatsby build don't work well together

Tags: firebase, gatsby

I get the following error when I try to login:

u.a.auth is not a function

The error is on this line in Login.js:

```
app.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);
```

At the top, I have `import app from "./base.js";`

In base.js, I have

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

var config = {
....
};

var app;
if(firebase.apps && firebase.apps.length > 0) {
  app = firebase.apps[0];
} else {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
export default app;
```

That's after I run

gatsby build

gatsby serve

Answer (score 0):

Hello here's how I did it. It worked fine:

```
import React from "react";
import firebase from "firebase";
...

const LoginForm = () => {

  const login = values => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
      .then(() => { firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
        navigate("/app/profile");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("do something with the error:", error);
      });
  }

  return(
    <form onSubmit={login}>
    form details
    </form>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```